# Extract image from an RTSP gives me errors

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using FFMPEG in a DOS Prompt.

```
-i rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.0.17:554/video_0 -q:v 15 -s 360x240 -vf \"select='eq(pict_type,PICT_TYPE_I)'\" -vsync vfr -f mjpeg -i -
```

I am getting the error:

```
ffmpeg version N-69779-g2a72b16 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 18.100 / 54. 18.100
  libavcodec     56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavformat    56. 21.100 / 56. 21.100
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 11.100 /  5. 11.100
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Option q:v (use fixed quality scale (VBR)) cannot be applied to input file - -- you are trying to apply an input option to an output file or vice versa. Move this option before the file it belongs to.
Error parsing options for input file -.
Error opening input files: Invalid argument
```

Instead of 'mjpeg' I have tried this 'image2pipe' which gives me the same error.

What should I be using?

Comment: You're missing `-f` to specify the format. Is that an error? Full command line and uncut command line output is missing. Please always include that.

Comment: @slhck so sorry in the delay to my response:  I have amended my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `-i -` at the end. `-i` specifies an input file or location. Just use `-`.

Comment: Hi, you are right th 'i; should not have been there.  I run it and I get my images for about 10 seconds and then it just freezes? Any ideas or should I post as a new question do you think?

Comment: In that case (since it really was just a minor error), you can also update the question with the new command and the corresponding output, and I'll delete my answer. Just drop me a comment.

Comment: Hi, the problem I got with this is that I run that command under a process in C#. to run it from the commandline I would have to change the output not to a pipe? If I post this question under StackOverFlow because it involves using C# people will not answer it because it really is an issue with ffmpeg. Unless you know for certain whether that my amended argument list is 100% correct? What are the possible reasons for it to 'seize'?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know why it would just stop, except for maybe having too many packets lost in the input, with the decoder crashing. Stack Overflow would be ok to ask if it involves C#, there are also people who know about ffmpeg. But even if you use a pipe, you can do that on the command line and provide the output. Just redirect the pipe away, e.g. `ffmpeg … -f mjpeg - > /dev/null`.

Comment: i have added -f mjpeg 2>error.txt - > null and have left it running

Comment: Does not seem to error. Must be my rubbish C# code :(